# Intercepting searchbar events using the Firefox add-on sdk

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am making a firefox add-on using the add-on sdk, also known as Jetpack.

What I need is to intercept events, especially pasting in the searchbar and the possibility of cancelling it due to user feedback. How can I register a listener that makes this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to check for changes to the searchbar like this (from your overlay):

```
var searchbar = document.getElementById("searchbar");
searchbar.addEventListener("change", function(e) { // do something // }, false);
```

Your handler will be called whenever the contents of the searchbar change so you can take appropriate action.

Comment: A reasonable answer, but I can't get this to work. The getElementById function is not returning an element. The add-on sdk has replaced the concept of overlays with content scripts, and they seem to behave differently.

Comment: I see. In the content script, the DOM is that of the content page not the browser window, so there is no element with the "searchbar" ID. I'm not 100% sure but you could try listening for the "open" event of windows.BrowserWindows and add the event listener to the window that is passed into the callback, which should presumably be the browser (i.e chrome) window.

Comment: Ok, I got it right by using the window-utils module (part of the lower level api modules). Then I can track windows and run javascript with more privileges so your code snippet works fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [DOM Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/) add-on to find out the search bar's id.
2. In your source code:

   ```
   var utils = require('sdk/window/utils');

   var doc = utils.getMostRecentWindow().document;
   var searchbar = doc.getElementById("searchbar");
   searchbar.addEventListener("change", /* your callback function here */ );
   ```